# alternatives to polling for changes to a ManagementObjectSearcher search result

Tags: wmi

I am using ManagementObjectSearcher to detect the availability of a bluetooth device:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher("select Name from Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Name = 'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator'")
```

I'd like to know as the application runs if such device is added or removed.  Is there a way to do that without polling the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a ManagementEventWatcher and set up a method to handle the events when it occurs.  Its described in this stackoverflow post

[Using WMI to identify which device caused a Win32_DeviceChangeEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278860/using-wmi-to-identify-which-device-caused-a-win32-devicechangeevent?rq=1)